# How to add custom methods to Laravel Carbon

Tags: laravel

I've been searching this problem for 2 days but no luck. I want to add custom methods to laravel carbon. I use the syntax below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Helpers;

use Carbon\CarbonInterface;

interface CarbonJalaliInterface extends CarbonInterface {

    public function toJalaliDateTimeString($unitPrecision = 'second');
    public function toJalaliDateString($unitPrecision = 'second');

}

abstract class CarbonJalali implements CarbonJalaliInterface {

    public function toJalaliDateTimeString($unitPrecision = 'second') {
        list($part1, $part2) = explode(' ', $this->rawFormat('Y-m-d '.static::getTimeFormatByPrecision($unitPrecision)));
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $part1);
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $part2);
        $timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
        include_once ('jdf.php');
        $jalali_date = jdate("H:i:s - Y/m/d",$timestamp);
        return $jalali_date;
    }

    public function toJalaliDateString($unitPrecision = 'second') {
        $timezone = 0;
        list($part1, $part2) = explode(' ', $this->rawFormat('Y-m-d'));
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $part1);
        $timestamp = mktime($month, $day, $year);
        include_once ('jdf.php');
        $jalali_date = jdate("Y/m/d",$timestamp);
        return $jalali_date;
    }

}
```

But i get the error:

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException DateTimeInterface can't be implemented by user classes`

I want to use it like this :

```
CarbonJalali::now()->toJalaliDateTimeString();
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: why did you make your class abstract btw?

Comment: @lagbox because the IDE suggested to make it abstract or implement all other methods of Carbon

Comment: why are you not extending the Carbon class itself or Laravel's extended version that already defines all the methods? you are making some random class that implements some random interface, at this point ... and if your class is abstract you can't get an instance of it